# Ghost shortcuts appearing in Windows Search for deleted folders

Tags: windows-explorer, shortcuts, windows-server-2012

I searched for some files on Server 2012r2 and the search results turned up matches in a folder shown as type = shortcut.  When right-click to Open File Location, there is no such folder.  Which is true - it was deleted.  But it shows up in search.

That folder was deleted and it's contents moved to a different folder during a "spring clean".

Example was "d:\software\registry hacks\"

The contents were moved to multiple folders as this = d:\software\registry\tweaks\  with sub folders under that for specific topics like \printing \desktop \chrome, etc.

Why does it still show up and how can I get rid of this non-existent shortcut showing up?

Comment: Have you rebuilt the Search index? https://www.techjunkie.com/how-to-solve-windows-search-issues-index-rebuild/

Comment: Rebuilding the index for a server with tens of thousands of files is not trivial, it takes ages + bogs it down.  Further, the whole point of it _should_ be that it notices changes.

These were made weeks ago.

FWIW I did as suggested overnight and it did fix it.  But why would it not notice and update the index?  Another question to post?

Comment: That's MS indexing. Not sure why you'd use it on a server.

Comment: What do you mean that's MS indexing and not use on a server?  Its what Server 2012 used to index to do searches from File Explorer - and when you search from a client on a server share, the client PCs search results _are from the server_ not local.  

Baffled by that MS Indexing thing. Care to explain what alternative you might have?

Comment: 1. Most servers I've used did *not* allow searches, particularly because it indexes across users. 2. There are many other search utilities for non-servers: https://alternativeto.net/software/windows-search/

Comment: Your said "Have you rebuilt the Search index?"  How does that connect with your last comment to use 3rd party software and why I'd use MS indexing on the server?  

Also, if a user on that domain searches from a mapped drive at their PC they are getting access to what they are allowed to see.  Hence the "across users" thing is moot.

Disabling search would mean that user 'x' searching for file on their shared locations on the server would always have to wait while Windows finds it which is crazy long if not indexed.  And that happens at the server.